# Rewriting MySQL subquery to be a join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a table with a lot of rows, and it's very inefficient to do subqueries on. I can't wrap my head around how to do a join on the data to save time.

Here is what I have:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ab0c/3/0

Comment: Right, sorry. The error I'm running into right now is that I'm trying to correlate the joined tables date with the main selects date value. It's not letting me do so. i.e. my select table is t1 and my joined table is t2. When I try to specify t2.date > t1.date in my join it throws [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 't1.date' in 'where clause', I'm usually pretty good at finding the answer on mine own, but this one is stumping me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

First, I think you are missing an `ORDER BY` in the subquery.  I suspect you want `order by I2.date` to get the "next" row.

Second, MySQL doesn't quite offer the functionality you need.  You could rewrite the query using variables.  But, because you don't describe what it is doing, it is hard to be sure that a rewrite would be correct.  That is one way to speed the query.

Third, this query would be much faster -- and probably fast enough -- with an index on `items(location, sku, date)`.  That index is probably all you need.

Comment: You're correct about the order by I was missing.

I don't quite understand your second point.

I unfortunately don't have control to modify table design currently. I was trying to make due without adding indexes, I actually can't even tell if there are indexes on said table.

Comment: @gordon-linoff is correct, what you are trying to do, which is to match the date with only the next date, can only be achieved using variable and not join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT I1.*, MIN(I2.exit_date)
FROM Items I1

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT date as exit_date, location, sku 
  FROM Items
  ORDER BY date asc
) as I2
ON I2.exit_date > I1.date
  AND I2.location = I1.location
  AND I2.sku = I1.sku 
GROUP BY I1.id
```